# Change clear button tooltip text from clear to other text in kendo-multiselect in using angular

Tags: angular, kendo-multiselect

In my angular app, I’m using kendo-multiselect.
I’m trying to change the x button text from clear to other value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.